# Toggle chart series in clojurescript

Tags: clojure

I'm toggling on/off series in chart and was wondering if I was doing anything crazy.

Is the atom really a good idea here?

```
;; ================ Graph data ================

(def serie1 {:label "Bar" :data [[11 13] [19 11] [30 -7]]})
(def serie2 {:label "Foo" :data [[10 1] [17 -14] [30 5]]})
(def serie3 {:label "Zon" :data [[8 2] [18 7] [30 15]]})


(def series (for [serie [serie1 serie2 serie3]]
              {:label (:label serie) :action "toggle-serie" :param serie}))

;; ============ Chart state ================

(def !chart
  "Chart state"
  (atom []))

(defn toggle-serie! [serie]
  "Return the series collection minus/plus the given serie"
  (swap! !chart #(if (some #{serie} %)
                   (remove #{serie} %)
                   (conj % serie))))


(defn reset-chart []
  "Reset chart state"
  (reset! !chart []))

;;================ Page population ================


; almost identical to ibdknox overtone example
(defpartial button [{:keys [label action param]}]
  [:a.button {:href "#" :data-action action :data-param param} label])

(defn populate [container buttons]
  (doseq [b buttons]
    (append container (button b))))

(populate ($ :#series) series)


;; ================ Button functions ================

(defn plot
  "Plot the given series and return the chart as an object."
  [placeholder coll-data & options]
  (js/jQuery.plot placeholder (clj->js coll-data) (clj->js options)))

(def chart ($ :#chart))

(defn toggle-serie-and-update-chart!
  "Add or remove a serie form the chart atom and redraw the chart."
  [serie]
  (toggle-serie! serie) ;update the chart atom
  (plot chart @!chart)) ; redraw the chart

(delegate ($ :#series) button :click
          (fn [e]
            (.preventDefault e)
            (this-as me 
                     (let [$me ($ me)
                           param (cljs.reader/read-string (data $me :param))]
                       (toggle-serie-and-update-chart! param)))))
```

Answer (score 2):

If your dataset were coming from an outside source, like an API call, I'd say the atom would make sense.  In this case, your dataset is static.  In that case, I think I might find it more intuitive to use a var for the series and then select the items out that you want to plot.   In that case, your state is really just a list of which series (you are selecting).

So, if you had all your series:

```
(def all-series
  {:series1 :...series1
   :series2 :...series2
   :series3 :...series3})
```

`!chart` might contain `#{:series1 :series3}` and you could get all the values out using `(select-keys all-series @!chart)`.

You might find you can avoid the atom altogether, but at the very least I'd always look for ways to keep that state as simple as